# Annoying Popups when Coding Python with VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code to write a tkinter project in Python.  Every time I create a widget, an annoying large pop-up occurs, with all of the properties for that widget.  It screens out my code, so that I can't keep typing.  I'm not even sure which extension is causing it.  I don't think it's Pylance, because I have that disabled.

I have to hit the escape button to make the pop-up go away, and then it changes my cursor from an i-beam to a block, so that I have to hit my ins key as well.  It is truly annoying.

Is there any way via the command palette to disable these "helpful" suggestions?  Yes, if I make a mistake or am stumped, I appreciate the correction, but not when I'm typing along in programming nirvana.

I think these pop-ups are being generated via the Microsoft Python Support extension or the Python Debugger.  I sure would like to disable these "helpful" suggestions until I really need them.

Comment: If you only retain Python Pylance extensions and disable other extensions, will this problem exist?

Comment: You can also display this prompt window in the form of pictures, which is convenient to find the question from which extension comes from